# How to uninstall ArgoCD from Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I've installed ArgoCD on my kubernetes cluster using

```
kubectl create namespace argocd

kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml
```

Now, how to remove it from the cluster totally?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can delete the entire installation using this - `kubectl delete -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml`

[Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/kayu97/how_to_uninstall_argocd/gfdlufl/)